# Self signed TLS cert not accepted only in ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm securing an internal web server using stunnel and easyRSA.

I've tried to use the default x509 types in easyRSA but my probes failed because the server cert does not have the `clientAuth`, I've added a new type of cert which adds the server and client auth

```
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth,clientAuth
```

Stunnel is configured with `verify=2` which should also check client certificates

This is my signing certs structure:

```
Root.CA
  | Signer.CA
  |  | server.crt
  |  | clientA.crt
  |  \ clientB.crt
  | WebClient.CA
  |  | server.crt
  |  | user.alice.crt
  |  \ user.bob.crt
  | RPC.CA
  |  | server.crt
  |  | rpcClient1.crt
  |  | rpcClient2.crt
  \  \ rpcClient3.crt
```

The idea is to use client certificates on webpages and have a central CA that will be trusted everywhere it is needed. This works fine with nginx client certs

But the rpc client in ruby can't verify the server cert. I'm using this code to debug the connection

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'net/http'

host = 127.0.0.1 # Not really but for example
port = 443

ruby = File.join(RbConfig::CONFIG['bindir'], RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_install_name'])
ruby_version = RUBY_VERSION
if patch = RbConfig::CONFIG['PATCHLEVEL']
  ruby_version += "-p#{patch}"
end
puts "%s (%s)" % [ruby, ruby_version]

openssl_dir = OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_AREA
mac_openssl = '/System/Library/OpenSSL' == openssl_dir
puts "%s: %s" % [OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION, openssl_dir]
[OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV, OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV].each do |key|
  puts "%s=%s" % [key, ENV[key].to_s.inspect]
end

ca_file = ENV[OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE_ENV] || OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE
ca_path = (ENV[OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR_ENV] || OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_DIR).chomp('/')

puts "\nHEAD https://#{host}:#{port}"
http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
http.use_ssl = true

# Explicitly setting cert_store like this is not needed in most cases but it
# seems necessary in edge cases such as when using `verify_callback` in some
# combination of Ruby + OpenSSL versions.
http.cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
http.cert_store.set_default_paths

http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.verify_depth = 5
failed_cert = failed_cert_reason = nil

# http.ca_file = File.read('ca.crt')
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('tls.crt'))
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('tls.key'))

if mac_openssl
  warn "warning: will not be able show failed certificate info on OS X's OpenSSL"
  # This drives me absolutely nuts. It seems that on Rubies compiled against OS X's
  # system OpenSSL, the mere fact of defining a `verify_callback` makes the
  # cert verification fail for requests that would otherwise be successful.
else
  http.verify_callback = lambda { |verify_ok, store_context|
    if !verify_ok
      failed_cert = store_context.current_cert
      failed_cert_reason = "%d: %s" % [ store_context.error, store_context.error_string ]
    end
    verify_ok
  }
end

user_agent = "net/http #{ruby_version}"
req = Net::HTTP::Head.new("/?#{rand()}", 'user-agent' => user_agent)

begin
  res = http.start { http.request(req) }
  abort res.inspect if res.code.to_i >= 500
  puts "OK"
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  puts "Error: connection refused"
  exit 1
rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
  puts "#{e.class}: #{e.message}"

  if failed_cert
    puts "\nThe server presented a certificate that could not be verified:"
    puts "  subject: #{failed_cert.subject}"
    puts "  issuer: #{failed_cert.issuer}"
    puts "  error code %s" % failed_cert_reason
  end

  ca_file_missing = !File.exist?(ca_file) && !mac_openssl
  ca_path_empty = Dir["#{ca_path}/*"].empty?

  if ca_file_missing || ca_path_empty
    puts "\nPossible causes:"
    puts "  `%s' does not exist" % ca_file if ca_file_missing
    puts "  `%s/' is empty" % ca_path if ca_path_empty
  end

  exit 1
end
```

This is the output:

```sh
$ ruby client.rb
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby (2.7.0-p0)
OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE=""

HEAD https://127.0.0.1:443
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:
  subject: /C=US/ST=State/L=Location/O=My Certificates/OU=Security/CN=myCN/emailAddress=signer@cn.app
  issuer: /C=US/ST=State/L=Location/O=My Certificates/OU=Security/CN=myCN/emailAddress=signer@cn.app
  error code 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Possible causes:
  `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/' is empty
```

If I create a cert bundle with `cat root.crt rpc.crt > bundle.crt` and set the `SSL_CET_FILE` to it I get:

```sh
$ SSL_CERT_FILE=bundle.crt ruby client.rb

/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby (2.7.0-p0)
OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE="/Users/user/easyrsa/certs/rpc/bundle.crt"

HEAD https://127.0.0.1:443
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected)

The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:



  subject: /C=US/ST=State/L=Location/O=My Certificates/OU=Security/CN=server@rpc/emailAddress=signer@cn.app
  issuer: /C=US/ST=State/L=Location/O=My Certificates/OU=Security/CN=rpc@ca/emailAddress=signer@cn.app
  error code 0: ok

Possible causes:
  `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/' is empty
```

Which tells me it can connect, but it is not being accepted anyway

I've tried to verify the connection with `OpenSSL` and I can connect and get a response:

```sh
openssl s_client -host 127.0.0.1 -port 443 -state -debug \
  -cert tls.crt \
  -key key.crt \
-CAfile <(kubectl get secret tls-explorer -n explorer --output="jsonpath={ .data.ca\.crt }" | base64 -d)

# If I then type "GET / HTTP/1.1" it returns me the contents
```

Also I'm using Paw as a postman replacement, and with it I can connect just fine with any of the rpc client cert

So what could be the problem?

Comment: You may have two versions of OpenSSL installed. The one in the default path and the one Ruby uses, based o the error message I would assume it is installed in  in `/usr/local/bin`. So have you installed your custom root CA certificate in `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/` as the error message indicates?

Comment: I'm using ruby with rvm and OpenSSL from brew. I didn't want to install the certs anywhere but for debugging I've installed the root and the intermediary CA certificate on keychain. If you see the logs, the cert is verified `error code 0: ok` but the actual request fails with `certificate rejected`. The final goal isn't to install the cert on the machine, is to pass the `ca.crt` to the script so it can do a double verification (server - client and client - server)